# Use $addToSet condition vise in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have below mongodb query, in which i am using `$addToSet`, Now i want to use it condition vise.

```
Worksheet.aggregate([
    {
     "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "todayBilling": {
          "$sum": {
            "$cond": [{ "$and" : [ { "$eq": [ "$isBilling", true] }, { $eq: [ "$date",new Date(moment().format('l'))]}] },"$hours",0 ] 
          }
        },
        "todayProjects": { "$addToSet": "$projectId" }
      },
    },
    { "$addFields": { "todayProjects": { "$size": "$todayProjects" }}},
    {
      "$lookup":{
        "from": "projects",
        "let": {},
        "pipeline": [
          { 
            "$group": { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": 1 } }
          }
        ],
        "as": "totalProjects"
      }
    },
    {'$unwind':'$totalProjects'}
  ])
```

Now, I want to get the count of `todayProjects` field if got result **today date vise**. means where `"todayProjects": { "$addToSet": "$projectId" }` exists, i want to use $cond with below condition:

> { $eq: [ "$date",new Date(moment().format('l'))]}

Comment: use `$match` after the `$group` stage. `{ $match: { todayProjects: { $ne: [] }}}`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, I need to get the todayProjects with the condition of current date.

Comment: What is the format of the date Field?

Comment: It is of "Date" type.

Comment: What you do is correct, I just want to use $addToSet with condition vise. So that i can get result of the current date, not of previous date.

Comment: You want the data filter with date?

Comment: $match after $group is giving me error.

Comment: yes, Below is my condition which i want to use:


"$cond": [ { "$eq":["$date", new Date(moment().format('l'))] }]

Comment: Have you used $lte $gte with the date Field?

Comment: No, I dont want to use. I just want to get the data current date vise.

Comment: No I am not getting you please try explain it with some sample collection and the output

Comment: { "$addFields": { "todayProjects": { "$size": "$todayProjects" }}}

Comment: This expression is getting the size of the todayProjects, Right?

Comment: Okay, If you are not getting it, I will edit my question shortly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54097090/get-count-of-distinct-field-values-condition-vise-in-mongodb,

please have a look at above question, it includes what i want with proper explanation.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, Are you checking it?

Comment: Post the expected output as well

Comment: okay, will post within 2 minutes.

Comment: done, please check.

Comment: What does current date wise means? Still unclear what you are asking

Comment: i just need to sum only one time for same project Id.

Comment: As my new posted question contains the documents with the same project Id, But when i count, It should be give 1 not 2.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, Can you please help me in my one more query?

Comment: Sure you can ask

Comment: Okay thanks, Should i ask a new question?

Comment: Yes please do..

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, Please have a look at below question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54360321/how-to-handle-find-if-collection-not-exists-in-mongodb